# Singleton Activity Class getInstance() Returns Null

Tags: java, android

I have an activity like:

```
public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static ListActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        Log.i("List", "Instance Created");
        instance = this;
        Log.i("List", (instance == null) ? "null" : "not null");
    }

    public static ListActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

<del>When the app starts, LogCat will report:</del> Never mind:

```
I/List﹕ Instance Created
I/List﹕ not null
```

<del>But later on in my other activity,</del>

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.getInstance(), ListActivity.class));
ListActivity.getInstance().updateList(files);
```

will produce a null pointer exception for trying to access `updateList()` on a "null object reference". I also threw in a `Log.i()` right before the 2nd line to confirm that it's indeed a null...

Can somebody explain why?

Edit 1. Watered down version of `MainActivity` (`onCreate()` not watered down):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static MainActivity instance;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a memory leak, this is definitely not a correct android design pattern. The problem is you are assuming that when you pass the line:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.getInstance(), ListActivity.class));
```

your activity has been created. THIS IS WRONG!

In other words, running `startActivity` method does not INCLUDE running `onCreate` method of the activity that is supposed to run.

The above line only sends a message to the main looper to run the next activity at a later time (possibly a few msec).

---

Again:
**this is not a memory leak** - but it is definitely a **poor way of managing memory**. By keeping a reference to your activity you keep your UI components in the memory. You need look into a more appropriate design pattern to satisfy your need.

One possible way to have a flag in an external singleton with some THINGS_TO_BE_DONE_UPON_CREATING_LIST_VIEW data. And check these values in your onCreate and update your list and etc according to this information rather than keeping a static reference to the activity itself. This is very crude example:

```
Class MySingleton{
    public static String[] files;
}
```

in your `ListView`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    if (MySingleton.files!=null)
       updateList(MySingleton.files);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what it felt like at first. But then why does it say that `instaance` is not null when the app first starts?

Comment: Do you start with ListActivity when your app starts?

Comment: No, I start with `MainActivity`, one of the only two activities

Comment: Then the instance that is NOT NULL is the MainActivity static instance and not the list activity. Can you copy and paste your onCreate method of MainActivity in your question?

Comment: I don't think the one I tested for is `Main`'s instance as they're separate classes, so they shouldn't be sharing the same instance member, and I only had it print in `ListActivity`'s `onCreate()`

Comment: Something from your code is missing here.... You are basically saying when  your app starts the onCreate method of ListActivity gets called (since you can read the log). But on the other hand, you say the app starts with the MainActivity... This is only possible is 1==2 returns true! I just created an empty app with two activities. The onCreate method of the second activity does not get called when the app starts.

Comment: Oh my bad. I was testing a lot, and LogCat wasn't cleared. I must have mixed up one of the previous outputs with the ones that came after. I just cleared LogCat, and it seems like `onCreate()` doesn't get called when the app started. So now we're back at the delayed execution of `onCreate()` I guess

Answer (score 3):

First off- never do this.  Its a memory leak.  Never hold a static reference to an Activity or Context.  If you need to update data in it, that data may be appropriate for a singleton, but an Activity NEVER is.

Secondly-  are you sure that the list activity was ever shown?  If not then the variable would be null.  That also includes the case of the app being killed and later relaunched from the saved intent in the recents menu.

Comment: Yeah it's a simple demo app for a class task. It has only two activities. There's the main screen, press a button, and basically proceed to the list activity, and that's it. The second activity is not shown any time before

Comment: How is this a memory leak? The second time this activity goes to onCreate() method, it overrides the static reference that was pointing to the old instance. Since nothing is pointing to the old instance, it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Because it holds into your activity even after it finishes. That means no images, views, or any other resource will be cleaned up. It's the number 1 cause of oom problems in android

Comment: This is not a memory leak. This is an inefficient way of handling memory!

Comment: It's absolutely a leak. Memory didn't get freed when it should have been. That's the definition of one.